# Backtrace on android native code

Tags: android, android-ndk, native-code

can anyone let me know what does this backtrace log indicates . i am spawning a thread in my code .but  i am not able to undrstand what is wrong with that.

Thread creation code

pthread_create(&tid, &attr, (void*(*)(void*))threadFunc, arg);

```
>I/DEBUG   ( 6144): backtrace:
>I/DEBUG   ( 6144):     #00  pc 00014260  /system/lib/libc.so (dlmalloc+643)
>I/DEBUG   ( 6144):     #01  pc 00016f7f  /system/lib/libc.so (malloc+10)
>I/DEBUG   ( 6144):     #02  pc 00061797  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmJdwpPostLocationEvent(JdwpState*, JdwpLocation const*, unsigned long long, int)+124)
I/DEBUG   ( 6144):     #03  pc 000438e1  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmDbgPostLocationEvent(Method const*, int, Object*, int)+76)
I/DEBUG   ( 6144):     #04  pc 0002b940  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCheckBefore+504)
I/DEBUG   ( 6144):     #05  pc 0001e37c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 6144):     #06  pc 0002bba8  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+180)
I/DEBUG   ( 6144):     #07  pc 0005f831  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+272)
I/DEBUG   ( 6144):     #08  pc 0005f85b  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)
I/DEBUG   ( 6144):     #09  pc 00054413  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 6144):     #10  pc 00012e00  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+48)
I/DEBUG   ( 6144):     #11  pc 00012558  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+172)
```

Thank You

Comment: You are badly allocating memory in your thread somewhere. Are you using va_list perhaps?

Comment: no .. i am not using va_list ..

Comment: malloc() is failing in one of your threads.  This usually happens because of native heap corruption.  There may be an informative message in the `adb logcat` output.  This particular thread is attempting to notify the debugger that a breakpoint address has been reached.  When working with JNI, I strongly recommend enabling the `CheckJNI` feature.

Comment: i have tried using checkJNI ..but i am not getting any helpful output. every time i run the app , it is crashing at different points calling malloc. so not able understnd the issue. Can this be sue to low memory issue ?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that this happens due `pthread_create`? Try to use `ndk-stack` command(from NDK) to find out the root cause(or [android-ndk-stacktrace-analyzer](https://code.google.com/p/android-ndk-stacktrace-analyzer/wiki/Usage)):

```
adb logcat | ndk-stack -sym /path_to_your_project/obj/local/armeabi
```

Comment: i am already using and able to get the line where it is crashing. as i already mentioned ..every time i run the app ..it is crashing at different points.At the point it crashed ..the line has either malloc or memcpy.

Comment: As you are seeing different crash points each time, it is possibly a thread synchronization issue. As far as I know, static code analysis is the only possible way to solve the crash.